# Under what environment would a VM perform better: a virtual box VM on a lightweight Linux distro, or a hyper-v VM on windows server 2012?

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization, hyper-v

I would like to allow my modest laptop to host VMs for the purpose of software development. I’d like to run one VM at a time nothing more. I’d just like to know which of the suggested setups would utilise an average household laptop's resources better?

I’ve heard people refer to Hyper-V as a 'type 1' VM host that runs direct on the hardware while VirtualBox is 'type 2' that runs on top of a host OS. That makes me think Hyper-V would be better.

Comment: Why not trying it by yourself ?

Comment: All type-1 hypervisors come with a “dom0” of sorts. With Hyper-V, it’s incredibly fat—a whole Windows instance.

Comment: NaeiKinDus - as this a question and answer site I sought to gain insight from other's experiences rather than reinvent the wheel by spending hours trying out both setups and comparing and contrasting. I believe this is the basis of a Q&A site. I hope I can offer others the same time saving insight through my answers.

Comment: @Daniel B, I suspected the Windows Server overhead to be quite a significant burden actually. So all that overhead would outweigh the 'type 1' advantage?

Comment: Fair enough, maybe it is too broad, I guess I just wanted a bit of anecdotal evidence to push me one way or the other really - that's probably the realm of a messageboard, sorry

Comment: As stated by @JakeGould, this is wayyyy to open-ended. It depends on so many factors that I don't think a canonical answer is even possible. A good idea would be to test it for yourself, post the result, and ask for more input / advices regarding the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are essentially asking if a Type 1 or Type 2 hypervisor is better.

> I’ve heard people refer to Hyper-V as a 'type 1' VM host that runs direct on the hardware

What this reduces down to is that Hyper-V is already running one VM as soon as setup is complete - your existing OS.  So you have a Type 1 HV, your main OS VM, and another OS VM.

The other way, installing a virtualization application on your existing OS, will not introduce another layer between your existing OS and the hardware.  But the guest OS will perform slightly slower.

It's difficult to say for sure as VMWare ESX, for example, and Hyper-V are different products and may perform differently under given scenarios.  It's probably more important, if performance is a concern, to give your VM its own disk so it's not interfering with your host OS, and ensure it has plenty of RAM and virtual CPU cores.